# Front camera of iphone 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone application development.Please tell me how i check through our application front camera are open or not,i have no iphone with os 4.0.

is any idea to check this.

Thanks

Comment: I believe iOS 4 is still under NDA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the XCode documentation. Search for "Front Camera" and you will find everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i see the documentation that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the WWDC 2010 videos are [available for free](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), I recommend watching Session 421 - Incorporating the Camera and Photo Library in your App and Session 409 - Using the Camera with AV Foundation.  I believe both of them cover this at some point.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is to detect if your device has got front-facing camera.                               For that you need to iterate through the video devices.

Try this method of UIImagePickerController:

```
 + (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)cameraDevice
```

This is a class method and UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice can take two values:

- UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear
- UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront
  Example code:

  ```
  if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:                         UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
  {
      // do something
  }
  ```

  Note that this is available for iOS 4.0 and later.

Also I am not sure if there is any API's to start the front-facing camera up front. The  camera always seems to start in the same mode that the user left it the last time it was used. Maybe by design Apple did not expose any API's to change this. Maybe Apple wanted the users to make a call on this.

Nevertheless you can atleast detect the availability of Fron Camera & provide your feature.

Inside the method where you call the picker for the first time:

```
picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Hope this answers your question.